# Friday in Düsseldorf, Munich by Sunday night. Can we visit Black Forest in between?

Tags: germany, munich, dusseldorf

We are on a tight schedule during our Germany business trip. We will be in Düsseldorf till Friday evening and have to be in Munich by Sunday night. Is there any way we can squeeze a short trip to Black Forest in the weekend? We are a team of four. How much it would cost us?

Comment: The Black Forest is a comparatively large place (for Germany anyway) and it's out of way from Dusseldorf to Munich.  But depending upon your definition of 'short trip' you might be able to do something immediately to the south of Stuttgart.  Not sure what a team of four has to do with it, driving spells? Unclear.

Comment: Why do you particularly want to visit "the black forest"?  Yes, you could trivially drive there and then on to Munich.  Plenty of time.  The best place to stay is the **Hotel Diana**.  Eat the hotel's amazing food or go down to one of the places on the lake.

Comment: South of Stuttgart? Can you please explain further? I mentioned team size just in case there are group discounts at hotels etc. No one is driving here.

Comment: @JoeBlow : Is it per person cost?

Comment: I'd say 1000 - 1500 euros in total for everyone.  I mean it's 100 each per night at a hotel (two nights) and food and car.

Comment: Have you considered simply going directly to Munich and spending the whole weekend there?  It's a fantastic city.  If you particularly want to see Freiburg, or look at the black forest (it's just some trees you drive through for ten minutes), just drive to Munich via that way.  Or forget that and just take the train to Munich, no need to rent a car, and enjoy the city.

Comment: Going from Düsseldorf to e.g. Freiburg and from Freiburg to Munich is just about 4 hours each either by car or train, meaning that you can spend almost two complete days in Freiburg and still keep your schedule. Why are you asking if this is feasible? The cost of getting there, staying, eating and entertainment can for four persons and two nights range from probably less than 400€ to easily 10000€ if you go for 'top of the class'.

Comment: indeed @Tor-EinarJarnbjo the rather iconoclastic, extremely expensive, yet overpriced, Colombi hotel is painfully expensive. It remains one of the few genuinely family owned posh hotels.

Comment: @JoeBlow : Thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Staying in Freiburg != visiting the Black Forest. As usual, starting from the assumption that people are not stupid might help understanding.

Comment: @Relaxed Sure, assuming that I am not stupid might help you understand. I am honestly not sure how you would visit the Black Forest without going to a place in the Black Forest. Care to enlighten me? If it is about travelling around within the Black Forest, I am not sure why having two days there would not solve that problem either.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I see you resort to your usual technique of saying something, anything, no matter how absurd, to never admit any mistake. Nobody said you didn't need to go there but that's only half the battle. Travelling around the Black Forest is obviously a big part of what this question is about and talk of spending two days in Freiburg is completely beside the point. You can say what you want about the rest now that you understood the question, your initial comment will remain silly (which is particularly funny when you are at the same time so condescending).

Comment: hi @jay on this surprisingly controversial question, can you state what TIME you can leave Düsseldorf Friday?  do you already have a car?  are you at the airport (convention?) or downtown?  For very short break planning - the devil is in the details.  If you can't leave town until (say) 7pm that is completely different than if you can leave town at (say) 4pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered simply going directly to Munich and spending the whole weekend there? It's a fantastic city. Just take the train to Munich, no need to rent a car, and enjoy the city. Be sure to choose (any) hotel in the old town, or you miss the whole point.

If you do for some reason want to see "the Black Forest" you realistically need a car. (It's an "area", rather than one destination.) You can do that easily on Friday night; depending on traffic you will get there late Friday night (leave Düsseldorf as early as possible to enjoy yourselves more). Yes, you can trivially drive to Munich airport Sunday from Schwarzwald area. So it's a simple 2-day car rental, one way rental from Dusseldorf to Munich airport.

I strongly recommend Hotel Diana in the Black Forest. Take all meals there!

Comment: While it might be cheaper by rental car, which is not a given, it is certainly possible to visit the Black Forest by train, even in just a weekend.

Comment: Hmm.  It would (for example) cost an incredible amount of $ to take a taxi from (where - Frieburg station - a dump) to some hotel "in the Black Forest". And how can you visit a rural location without a car? (Unless you're just sitting at a resort.) However, I did assume train connections would be crappy since it's kind of a rural destination; but you're right, there does seem to be reasonably quick connections from Dusseldorf.

Comment: Going by car from Düsseldorf to Munich will take you at least 5 hours as well, provided that there is no traffic. On a Friday evening with additional weekend traffic, I would call you very lucky if you manage to drive in less than 7 hours.

Comment: @JoeBlow Ever heard of local trains and buses? I never use taxis while traveling and still manage to get to many places.

Comment: you know that's true enough, @Tor-EinarJarnbjo.  Notice the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: hi @Willeke I much prefer train travel.  As I said, my top recommendation is that the OP **takes a train to Munich** and leaves it at that.  Notice the first paragraph. However there are some destinations, regions, where train/bus does not work and it's really about having a car.

Comment: The point of the car is not to go from Düsseldorf to the south. You could even take the train and get a car in Freiburg. And I am not sure why everybody is discussing Freiburg. It has its quirks but at the end of the day, it's just another German city, which happens to be located in the area. But if visiting a city is what you want, there are countless better choices (including Munich). The Black Forest is something else: the lakes, landscape, small villages, etc. And Joe is right, for that you basically need a car, everything else is very slow and limiting.

Comment: right, you need a car to see the "black forest", I'd say.  I think the only reason Frieburg is mentioned is it is rather the "Gateway to the Black Forest!"  :)  plus it has those cool drains in the street.

Comment: given that they have to travel "friday night" it would perhaps be impractical to take a train to Frieburg (or wherever) and then get a car, I think.  it would get too late; also a one-way (to Munich aeroport) may be less practical; plus it would pointlessly cost more I'd guess since you are renting a car anyways

Answer (score 4):

Can be done but it's not clear if it's worth it.

1. I would get a rental car: it's more cost efficient for 4 people, offers a lot of flexibility and you can drive on the Autobahn
2. Drive Friday night from Düsseldorf to a larger town close to the Schwarzwald. Karlsruhe or Baden Baden perhaps. Stay the night at a regular hotel. Check Travelocity for options. It's off season so you should get a room for $120 or less. It's 4 hour ride but will be more with traffic. Once you made it through Cologne you should be fine. By the time you get to Frankfurt it should have cleared out there. Make sure the hotel has 24-hour check in though.
3. Start driving leisurely through the Schwarzwald. It's fairly big and has lots of small villages. Stop for food and hiking, more food and beer. Stay in a small village inn or bed & breakfast. It's off season so you shouldn't have any problems to get rooms at very attractive prices ( < 100$) often including a heart-stopping breakfast.
4. On Sunday explore some more and then around noon time head for Munich. Should be a straight shot without a lot of traffic on the Autobahn.